# The DataSourceID of 'V4QuickLaunchMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource

Tags: error, xml, web-config, spnavigationnode, portalsitemapprovider

I am trying to make a left navigation bar to SharePoint 2010 with this teckniq=http://www.helpmeonsharepoint.com/2012/03/custom-sharepoint-top-menu-and.html

**I Have got this Error massage**:

> The DataSourceID of 'V4QuickLaunchMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'QuickLaunchSiteMap' could not be found.

**Sorce Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack trace**

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The DataSourceID of 'V4QuickLaunchMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'QuickLaunchSiteMap' could not be found.]
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetDataSource() +2335265
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ConnectToHierarchicalDataSource() +212
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +28
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +191
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

**I have found** that it can bee a lot of different reasont to why this hapend. I have tryed to change my XML file with out sucsess. I hope you will understand what I'm doing wrong.

I will post the parts of my code that i think is relevent Here is my code:

**In web.config** inside SiteMap-> providers I added this:

```
<add name="CustomNavigationProvider"
                                    type="BNS.Intranet.HR.CustomPortalNavigation, BNS.Intranet.HR, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" />
```

**cs-file**

```
    namespace BNS.Intranet.HR
{
    public class CustomPortalNavigation : PortalSiteMapProvider
    {
        public override SiteMapNodeCollection GetChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMapNode node)
        {
            PortalSiteMapNode pNode = node as PortalSiteMapNode;
            if (pNode != null)
            {
                if (pNode.Type == NodeTypes.Area)
                {
                    SiteMapNodeCollection nodeColl = base.GetChildNodes(pNode);
                    PortalSiteMapNode childNode = new PortalSiteMapNode(pNode.WebNode, "1", NodeTypes.Area, "http://sp2010dev04/navi/",
                        "1", "1");

                    PortalSiteMapNode childNode1 = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        childNode1 = new PortalSiteMapNode(childNode.WebNode, "1.1" + i, NodeTypes.Area,
                                    "http://sp2010dev04/navi", "1.1", "1.1");
                    }

                    nodeColl.Add(childNode);
                    SiteMapNodeCollection test = new SiteMapNodeCollection();
                    if (childNode1 != null)
                    {
                        test.Add(childNode1);
                        childNode.ChildNodes = test;
                    }
                    return nodeColl;
                }
                else // Shouldn't it always return base.GetChildNodes?
                    return base.GetChildNodes(pNode);
            }
            else  // Only return new SiteMapNodeCollection when pNode is null?
                return new SiteMapNodeCollection();
        }
```

**Elements.xml-file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Control Id="QuickLaunchDataSource" Sequence="30"
             ControlClass="System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource"
             ControlAssembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicTokenKey=71e9bce111e9429">
        <Property Name="ID">QuickLaunchSiteMap</Property>
        <Property Name="SiteMapProvider">CustomSiteMapProvider</Property>
        <Property Name="EnableSecurityTrimming">false</Property>
        <Property Name="EnableViewState">true</Property>
        <Property Name="ShowStartingNode">false</Property>
        <Property Name="StartingNodeOffset">0</Property>
        <Property Name="StartFromCurrentNode">false</Property>
    </Control>
    <HideCustomAction Id="QuickLaunch"
                     HideActionId="QuickLaunch"
                     GroupId="Customization"
                     Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings" />
</Elements>
```

**My delegate controls in the masterpage**

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl5" runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
    <Template_Controls>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ShowStartingNode="False" id="QuickLaunchSiteMap" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025" runat="server" />
                 </Template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Two new ones

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="DelegateControl8">
  <Template_Controls>
   <asp:SiteMapDataSource
     ShowStartingNode="False"
     SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
     id="SiteMapDataSource1"
     runat="server"
     StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
  </Template_Controls>
 </SharePoint:DelegateControl>

<SharePoint:DelegateControl ID="DelegateControl9" runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchDataSource">
<Template_Controls>
  <asp:SiteMapDataSource SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
ShowStartingNode="False"
id="SiteMapDataSource2"
StartingNodeUrl="sid:1025"
runat="server" />
 </Template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Comment: Can You post  your SharePoint Delegate Control Code

Comment: Hello Ashish, I have added my delegate controle to the question now.

Comment: There are 2 Delegate controls.

Comment: There are? Then where should I finde the one you want to see?

Comment: There is one more delegate control in that link. 1.Top Navigation Menu. Try adding it

Comment: you can vote me up than

Comment: I could if you type it as an answer and not a coment.

Comment: should i write it as answer again?

Comment: Yes, write it as an answer then I can wote you up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding Both Delegate controls and it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I didn't understand, what do you mean by both delegate controls ?